# Creating a column containing the other columns as a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying add a column to my dataframe that contains the information from the other columns as a json object

My dataframe looks like this:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

I'm then trying to add the json column using the following

```py
    for i, row in df:
        i_val = row.to_json()
        df.at[i,'raw_json'] = i_val
```

However it results in a "cascaded" dataframe where the json appears twice

| col_1 | col_2 | raw_json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"col_1":1,"col_2":1,"raw_json":{"col_1":1,"col_2":1}} |
| 2 | 2 | {"col_1":2,"col_2":2,"raw_json":{"col_1":2,"col_2":2}} |

I'm expecting it to look like the following

| col_1 | col_2 | raw_json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"col_1":1,"col_2":1} |
| 2 | 2 | {"col_1":2,"col_2":2} |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `df.to_json(orient='records')`

```
df['raw_json'] = df.to_json(orient='records')


   col_1  col_2                                       raw_json
0      1      1  [{"col_1":1,"col_2":1},{"col_1":2,"col_2":2}]
1      2      2  [{"col_1":1,"col_2":1},{"col_1":2,"col_2":2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comp and itterrows (your expected has a dict if you want json you can remove the [0]):

```
df["raw_json"] = [pd.DataFrame(data=[row], columns=df.columns).to_dict(orient="records")[0] for _, row in df.iterrows()]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col_1  col_2                  raw_json
0      1      1  {'col_1': 1, 'col_2': 1}
1      2      2  {'col_1': 2, 'col_2': 2}
```